# Kali Linux issue after update

Tags: linux, updates, kali-linux

My laptop is stuck like this since I have made an update
and this window cannot be closed.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: When writing a question, you can include images inline using the picture button.

Comment: Also, when possible, crop your images to the relevant content.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal session (I can see the Kali "Start" button upper left so you can do that).

Then:

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove

When this is done, restart Kali and it should be working properly.